# select into and if statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So, I have been trying to get this to work. I'm just frustrated I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to declare the variable num and insert a value into it using a select into statement with count.  After that I want to do a simple if statement that will run an update or delete based off of the outcome. I'm relatively new to Oracle Pl/SQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
DECLARE
   num   number;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO num
     FROM csteinkamp.gai
    WHERE breed_ref_id = 455;

   IF (num > 5)
   THEN
      UPDATE csteinkamp.gai
         SET animal_nm = 'TEST'
       WHERE breed_ref_id = 455;
   ELSE
      DELETE FROM csteinkamp.gai
            WHERE breed_ref_id = 455;
   END;
```

Comment: When asking questions like this, a more concrete description of the outcome and any error messages would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` ends with `end if`;

```
DECLARE
   num   number;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO num
     FROM csteinkamp.gai
    WHERE breed_ref_id = 455;

   IF (num > 5)
   THEN
      UPDATE csteinkamp.gai
         SET animal_nm = 'TEST'
       WHERE breed_ref_id = 455;
   ELSE
      DELETE FROM csteinkamp.gai
            WHERE breed_ref_id = 455;
   END IF; -- End if.
END; -- End of the program block.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. I didn't think my logic was that messed up, but I couldn't figure out what was wrong. The END IF; was all that I needed.

Comment: Your logic was fine, but sometimes you overlook something. It happens. :) Didn't you get any error messages?

Comment: Ya, it kept asking for an if statement. I completely forgot about the end if; so I tried 2 end; statements and kept getting the same thing. Sometimes you are just missing the smallest thing, which can get frustrating.

Comment: It probably asked for an `if` *keyword*, which is exactly what was missing. :) But sometimes those error messages are a bit too abstract. Anyway, it is solved now.